# What are some good work arounds to deal with the "Visiblility: Collapse" bug in Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox

## What are some good work arounds to deal with the "Visiblility: Collapse" bug in Mozilla Firefox?

### Context:

My friends in the comments informed me there is an old Firefox bug that causes the ***"visibility: collapse"*** CSS property to act like the ***"visibility: hidden"*** CSS property. This causes the table to be the full size with all of the visible columns shifted to the left and extra space to the right.

[image]

With larger tables this undesired behavior is even more drastic.

[image]

I just want to be able to toggle the visibility of the table columns and have it look the same on Chrome, Edge, and Firefox which leads to my question: What are some good work arounds to deal with the "Visiblility: Collapse" bug in Mozilla Firefox?

### Code:

Here is the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/jado66/pgyLm86e/18/

Here is the code in the fiddle:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        th{
            border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
        }
        td{
            text-align: center;
        }
        col{
            border: 1px solid grey;
            width: 55px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <table style="margin: auto; border: 1px solid black; border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse;">
            <colgroup>
                <col id = "col_1">
                <col id = "col_2">
                <col id = "col_3">
                <col id = "col_4" style="visibility: collapse">
                <col id = "col_5" style="visibility: collapse">
                <col id = "col_6">
            </colgroup>
            <tr>
                <th>Col 1</th>
                <th>Col 2</th>
                <th>Col 3</th>
                <th>Col 4</th>
                <th>Col 5</th>
                <th>Col 6</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1.1</td>
                <td>1.2</td>
                <td>1.3</td>
                <td>1.4</td>
                <td>1.5</td>
                <td>1.6</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Technically, the `visibility` property *is* working; otherwise, the values from columns 4 and 5 would be shown. What's *not* working is getting the table border to shrink to account for the hidden columns.

Comment: It could be related to [this ancient bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=77019), which was closed 18 years ago.

Comment: Yea I was writing about that bug @Richard Deeming, apparently is still there, well kinda. Apparently the bug is related to the collumns and not to the colgroup, now it got inverted, and is related to the colgroup and not to the collumn, soooo you have to find another way, becouse I don't know if there is a way to keep that table dynamicly width structured like this.

Comment: Found it: [819045 - table element borders draw incorrectly when col has visibility: collapse](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=819045) - still open, and last updated 5 years ago.

Comment: Also, there's a note in the browser compatibility section of the MDN docs: *Firefox doesn't hide borders when hiding `<col>` and `<colgroup>` elements if `border-collapse: collapse` is set.*

Comment: Well, I wrote another comment on that post, maybe someone will read it

Comment: Table layout has long had a reputation within browser makers of being a bag of grenades with loose pins. Best left well alone. Chromium has however introduced TablesNG, a new implementation that supposedly has much more thorough documentation of all the rules involved. Hopefully, this will be fed back into the CSS Tables Standard, and in due course we'll get not only fixes of long standing bugs like this one, but also some useful extensions to a very neglected part of CSS.

Comment: I don't care so much about the borders being shown. I have a table with a bunch of columns and the table isn't centered when there are collapsed columns because it is saving space for the columns like "visibility: hidden" is supposed to.

Comment: I've edited my question. The edited question is "How do I mitigate this bug?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As **@Richard Deeming** has pointed out, this rendering issue is related to the `border-collapse: collapse;` property.

If you can do without it and centering is also negligible –
removing the `border-collapse: collapse;` property from your table might be a valid compromise.

```js
function hideColumn(columns) {
  columns.forEach(function(num, i) {
    columns[i] = "#col_" + columns[i];
  });
  let selectors = columns.join(", ");
  // reset previously hidden
  let hidden = document.querySelectorAll(".collapsed-col");
  hidden.forEach(function(el) {
    el.classList.remove("collapsed-col");
  });
  // hide cells by class
  let cells = document.querySelectorAll(selectors);
  cells.forEach(function(item, i) {
    item.classList.add("collapsed-col");
  });
}


// test input
let inputHideColumns = document.querySelector(".inputHideColumns");
inputHideColumns.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  let value = e.target.value.replaceAll(", ", ",");
  let columns = value.split(",");
  hideColumn(columns);
});
```

```css
.collapsed-col {
  visibility: collapse;
}

table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  /*
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: auto; 
  */
  border: 1px solid black;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

th {
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div style="text-align: center;">
    <table>
      <colgroup>
        <col id="col_1">
        <col id="col_2">
        <col id="col_3">
        <col id="col_4" class="collapsed-col">
        <col id="col_5" class="collapsed-col">
        <col id="col_6">

      </colgroup>
      <tr>
        <th>Col 1</th>
        <th>Col 2</th>
        <th>Col 3</th>
        <th>Col 4</th>
        <th>Col 5</th>
        <th>Col 6</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1.1</td>
        <td>1.2</td>
        <td>1.3</td>
        <td>1.4</td>
        <td>1.5</td>
        <td>1.6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2.1</td>
        <td>2.2</td>
        <td>2.3</td>
        <td>2.4</td>
        <td>2.5</td>
        <td>2.6</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <p>
    <label>hide columns (comma seperated)</label>
    <input class="input inputHideColumns" type="text" placeholder="hide columns (comma seperated)" value="5,4">
  </p>

  </div>
```

An alternative approach might be to apply a 'collapsed-col' class to every th/td according to their column.

This approach would require your `th` and `td` elements to have a dedicated column class like `col_1`, `col_2` etc.

```js
function indexColumns(table) {
  let rows = table.querySelectorAll("tr");
  rows.forEach(function (row, r) {
    let cols = row.querySelectorAll("th, td");
    cols.forEach(function (col, c) {
      col.classList.add("tr_" + r);
      col.classList.add("col_" + (c + 1));
    });
  });
}

function hideColumn(columns) {
  columns.forEach(function (num, i) {
    columns[i] = ".col_" + columns[i];
  });
  let selectors = columns.join(", ");
  // reset previously hidden
  let hidden = document.querySelectorAll(".collapsed-col");
  hidden.forEach(function (el) {
    el.classList.remove("collapsed-col");
  });
  // hide cells by class
  let cells = document.querySelectorAll(selectors);
  cells.forEach(function (item, i) {
    item.classList.add("collapsed-col");
  });
}

// index th/td elements by setting class 
let table = document.querySelector('table');
indexColumns(table);
hideColumn([4, 5]);

// test input
let inputHideColumns = document.querySelector(".inputHideColumns");
inputHideColumns.addEventListener("change", function (e) {
  let value = e.target.value.replaceAll(", ", ",");
  let columns = value.split(",");
  hideColumn(columns);
});
```

```css
.layout {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

th {
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
}


.collapsed-col {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="layout">
    <div class="table-wrap">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Col 1</th>
            <th>Col 2</th>
            <th>Col 3</th>
            <th>Col 4</th>
            <th>Col 5</th>
            <th>Col 6</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1.1</td>
            <td>1.2</td>
            <td>1.3</td>
            <td>1.4</td>
            <td>1.5</td>
            <td>1.6</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2.1</td>
            <td>2.2</td>
            <td>2.3</td>
            <td>2.4</td>
            <td>2.5</td>
            <td>2.6</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>

      </table>
    </div>
    <p>
      <label>hide columns (comma seperated)</label>
      <input class="input inputHideColumns" type="text" placeholder="hide columns (comma seperated)" value="5,4">
    </p>
  </div>
```

Comment: I wish I could accept both answers!

Comment: After extra testing of both answers I've chosen to accept this answer instead. This answer is more scalable and works with different sized columns. Wish I could give you the bounty as well.

Comment: It also comforts me that this solution doesn't depend on <col> or <colgroup>

Answer (score 2):

If we observe in Developer tools we see that colgroup is overflowing. So if we clip overflow on table it clips some of the extra part. If we increase collapsed column width a little bit it clips perfectly:

```js
var c4, c5;

function toggle() {
  c4.classList.toggle('collapsed');
  c5.classList.toggle('collapsed');
}

function init() {
  c4 = document.querySelector('#col_4');
  c5 = c4.nextElementSibling;
}
```

```css
:root {
  --col-width: 55px;
}

th {
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
}

col {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: var(--col-width);
}

/* clip the overflow */
table {
  overflow: clip;
}

.collapsed {
  visibility: collapse;
  /* need to increase width slightly to make it work */
  /* some how addition doesn't work */
  width: calc(var(--col-width) * 1.2);
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<body onload="init()">
 <p>View this in Firefox browser</p>
  <div style="text-align: center;">
    <table style="margin: 0 auto;border: 1px solid black; border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse;">
      <colgroup>
        <col id="col_1">
        <col id="col_2">
        <col id="col_3">
        <col id="col_4" class="collapsed">
        <col id="col_5" class="collapsed">
        <col id="col_6">
      </colgroup>
      <tr>
        <th>Col 1</th>
        <th>Col 2</th>
        <th>Col 3</th>
        <th>Col 4</th>
        <th>Col 5</th>
        <th>Col 6</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1.1</td>
        <td>1.2</td>
        <td>1.3</td>
        <td>1.4</td>
        <td>1.5</td>
        <td>1.6</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div style="width: min-content; background-color: wheat; margin: 0 auto;;">mid</div>
  <button onclick="toggle()">Toggle collapse</button>
</body>

</html>
```

But this doesn't center the contents. Collapsed `col` still contributes to width.
If we add a div wrapper and set it's width (table width - collapsed width) then it may work:

```js
var c4, c5;

function toggle() {
  c4.style.visibility = c5.style.visibility = window.getComputedStyle(c4).visibility === 'collapse' ? '' : 'collapse';
}

function init() {
  c4 = document.querySelector('#col_4');
  c5 = c4.nextElementSibling;
  resize();

  //observe style change
  var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutationRecord) {
      resize();
    });
  });
  observer.observe(c4, {
    attributes: true,
    attributeFilter: ['style']
  });
}

//subtract collapsed width from wrapper
function resize() {
  var colgroup = document.querySelector('colgroup');
  var actualWidth = colgroup.offsetWidth;
  var reducedWidth = 0;

  for (var i = 0, len = colgroup.childElementCount; i < len; ++i) {
    var col = colgroup.children[i];
    if (window.getComputedStyle(col).visibility == 'collapse') {
      reducedWidth += col.offsetWidth;
    }
  }
  console.log(actualWidth + ' reduced by ' + reducedWidth);
  var wrapper = document.querySelector('#wrapper');
  wrapper.style.width = (actualWidth - reducedWidth) + 'px';
}
```

```css
th {
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
}

col {
  border-right: 1px solid grey;
  width: 55px;
}


/* added styles */

col:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

table {
  width: max-content;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

#wrapper {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: max-content;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<body onload="init()">
  <p>View this in Firefox browser.</p>
  <div id=wrapper style="text-align: center;">
    <table style="margin: auto; border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse;">
      <colgroup>
        <col id="col_1">
        <col id="col_2">
        <col id="col_3">
        <col id="col_4" style="visibility: collapse">
        <col id="col_5" style="visibility: collapse">
        <col id="col_6">
      </colgroup>
      <tr>
        <th>Col 1</th>
        <th>Col 2</th>
        <th>Col 3</th>
        <th>Col 4</th>
        <th>Col 5</th>
        <th>Col 6</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1.1</td>
        <td>1.2</td>
        <td>1.3</td>
        <td>1.4444444</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1.6</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div style="width: min-content; background-color: wheat; margin: 0 auto;;">mid</div>
  <button onclick="toggle()">Toggle collapse</button>
</body>

</html>
```

With this we are hiding the collapsed part using wrapper div.

---

If you want to scroll the table horizontally then you need add one more wrapper for the scroll:

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script>
    var c4, c5;

    function toggle() {
      c4.style.visibility = c5.style.visibility = window.getComputedStyle(c4).visibility === 'collapse' ? '' : 'collapse';
    }

    function init() {
      c4 = document.querySelector('#col_4');
      c5 = c4.nextElementSibling;
      resize();

      //observe style change
      var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function (mutationRecord) {
          resize();
        });
      });
      observer.observe(c4, {
        attributes: true,
        attributeFilter: ['style']
      });
    }

    //subtract collapsed width from wrapper
    function resize() {
      var colgroup = document.querySelector('colgroup');
      var actualWidth = colgroup.offsetWidth;
      var reducedWidth = 0;

      for (var i = 0, len = colgroup.childElementCount; i < len; ++i) {
        var col = colgroup.children[i];
        if (window.getComputedStyle(col).visibility == 'collapse') {
          reducedWidth += col.offsetWidth;
        }
      }
      console.log(actualWidth + ' reduced by ' + reducedWidth);
      var wrapper = document.querySelector('#wrapper');
      wrapper.style.width = (actualWidth - reducedWidth) + 'px';
    }
  </script>
  <style>
    th {
      border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
    }

    td {
      text-align: center;
    }

    col {
      border-right: 1px solid grey;
      width: 55px;
    }


    /* added styles */

    col:last-child {
      border-right: none;
    }

    table {
      width: max-content;
      overflow-y: hidden;
    }

    #wrapper {
      border: 1px solid;
      width: fit-content;
      overflow: hidden;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #scrollMe {
      width: 300px;
      overflow-x: auto;
      margin: 0 auto;
      border: 1px solid lime
    }

  </style>

  </style>
</head>

<body onload="init()">
  <p>View this in Firefox browser.</p>
  <div id="scrollMe">
    <div id=wrapper style="text-align: center;">
      <table style="margin: auto; border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse;">
        <colgroup>
          <col id="col_1">
          <col id="col_2">
          <col id="col_3">
          <col id="col_4" style="visibility: collapse">
          <col id="col_5" style="visibility: collapse">
          <col id="col_6">
        </colgroup>
        <tr>
          <th>Col 1</th>
          <th>Col 2</th>
          <th>Col 3</th>
          <th>Col 4</th>
          <th>Col 5</th>
          <th>Col 6</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1.1</td>
          <td>1.2</td>
          <td>1.3</td>
          <td>1.4444444</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1.6</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="width: min-content; background-color: wheat; margin: 0 auto;;">mid</div>
  <button onclick="toggle()">Toggle collapse</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Note: These are just workarounds.

Comment: I just noticed this doesn't work very well with variable column widths. If you add a couple more columns and change the widths it is easy to see how this breaks. 

https://jsfiddle.net/jado66/w673pbge/1/

Comment: I think the safest bet is to alter each affected cell. How can I transfer bounty to @herrstrietzel?

Comment: You can put a bounty on this question and award it to him. I think you should keep it. You worked hard too!

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/swxaob10/

If you don't mind every cell to have a class, here's an easy way. The idea is to add classes to the `<table>`, and each of these classes will make corresponding cells invisible. We can use JS to toggle the classes.

In the following example only the 2nd column will be shown.

```
<table class="col-1 col-3">
    <tr>
        <th class="col-1">Col 1</th>
        <th class="col-2">Col 2</th>
        <th class="col-3">Col 3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="col-1">1.1</td>
        <td class="col-2">1.2</td>
        <td class="col-3">1.3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="col-1">2.1</td>
        <td class="col-2">2.2</td>
        <td class="col-3">2.3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When the table has `.col-1` class, all cells with `.col-1` class will be hidden, and so on.

```
table.col-1 .col-1 { display: none; }
table.col-2 .col-2 { display: none; }
table.col-3 .col-3 { display: none; }
```